# Why does Cu not react with dilute H2SO4?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

$\ce{Cu + (dil) H2SO4 -> No Reaction}$

but

$\ce{Cu + (conc) H2SO4 -> CuSO4 + SO2 + H2O}$

What is the difference between the dilute and concentrated acid that one reacts but the other doesn't? They both are the same thing except that dilute one has more water than the concentrated one.

Comment: Dilute H2SO4 is an aqueous solution. Conc H2SO4 is not. Conc H2SO4 is a really reactive liquid.

Comment: It is not a bad question, often sulfuric acid is not regarded as oxidising while nitric acid is regarded as oxidizing